# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. nmap open ports print value not storing in sql table gives error

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm, nmap

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.

Getting this error because `dict_keys` are not able to be stored in the table column `Opened_ports`.
The code is okay for the SQL part it is the format how `dict_keys` are displayed `dict_keys([53, 80, 111, 443])` which are not being stored.

I tried `ns[ip_addr]['tcp'].keys().list()` didn't work says `dict_keys` doesn't have the attribute `list()`.

```
def db(*args):

    with sqlite3.connect('Test.db') as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
    ns, ip_addr, ports = args
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Scaninfo(
    scanID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ip_address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    scanned_ports VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Opened_ports VARCHAR(100),
    Hostname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ipaddress_state VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
    ''')
    cursor.execute("insert into Scaninfo (ip_address, scanned_ports, Opened_ports ,Hostname, ipaddress_state) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                   (ip_addr, ports, ns[ip_addr]['tcp'].keys(), ns[ip_addr].hostname(), ns[ip_addr].state() ))

    db.commit()

    def Report_csv():
        db_name = 'Test.db'

        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + db_name)
        df = pd.read_sql_table('Scaninfo', engine)
        df.to_csv('test.csv')
    Report_csv()
```

Comment: Thanks for edit @M.R

Answer (score 0):

I added this in the def db()

```
    for proto in ns[ip_addr].all_protocols():

    lport = ns[ip_addr][proto].keys()

    sorted(lport)
    port2 = ','
    port1= port2.join(str(port) for port in lport)

    (ip_addr, ports, port1, ns[ip_addr].hostname(), ns[ip_addr].state() ))
```

now it works